How to modify the size of the DateCalendar component of MUI?
I'm building web app and  wanted to use DateCalendar as my calendar component. Everything works fine, but I'm having an issue with resizing the calendar.
I tried styled but it doesn't seem to do anything as the MuiDateCalendar-root is being overwritten each time.
Has anyone had similar problem and found the solution?
const StyledDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)({
  ' & .MuiDateCalendar-root': {
    margin: '5px', /* Increase size */
    height: '800px',
    width: '800px',
  },
});



    <div className='bg-white pb-20 pt-36'>
  <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs} adapterLocale="en-gb">
    <StyledDateCalendar
      showDaysOutsideCurrentMonth
      loading={isLoading}
      onMonthChange={handleMonthChange}
      renderLoading={() => 
      <DayCalendarSkeleton />
    }
      slots={{
        day: (props: React.JSX.IntrinsicAttributes & PickersDayProps<dayjs.Dayjs> & { highlightedDays?: { type: string; date: string }[] | undefined; }) => <ServerDay {...props} highlightedDays={highlightedDays} />,
      }}
    />
  </LocalizationProvider>
</div>


You need to change all of the grid items' height, width and font-size manually like this:
const StyledDateCalendar = styled(DateCalendar)({
  '&.MuiDateCalendar-root': {
    margin: '5px',
    height: '800px',
    width: '800px',
    maxHeight: 'none',
    '& .MuiDayCalendar-weekDayLabel': {
      fontSize: '1rem',
    },
    '& div[role="row"]': {
      justifyContent: 'space-around',
    },
    '& .MuiDayCalendar-slideTransition': {
      minHeight: '500px',
    },
    '& .MuiPickersDay-root': {
      height: '50px',
      width: '50px',
      fontSize: '1rem',
    },
  },
});

You can take a look at this StackBlitz for a live working example.

thanks a lot, now I can see what I was missing.
